# OpenGL Segmentation Fault using TrueType

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, freetype

I've been trying to adopt the [TrueType](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02) OpenGL tutorial into my engine. When I compile and run their example, everything works correctly, but when I tried re-writing the code into my engine, I keep getting a segmentation fault. I then tried just copy pasting their code into my Utils header file, but it didn't work. I've done a bit of debugging with cout, and it seems like the fault is happening within my render method. I'll post the render method first, then all other TrueType related functions after it. If you need to ask me anything, then feel free.

**Render Method**:

```
void Util::Font::render(const char *text, Atlas *a, float x, float y, float sx, float sy)
{
glUseProgram(shaderID);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

const uint8_t *p;

/* Use the texture containing the atlas */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, a->tex);
glUniform1i(samplerID, 0);

/* Set up the VBO for our vertex data */
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

point coords[6 * strlen(text)];
int c = 0;

/* Loop through all characters */
for (p = (const uint8_t *)text; *p; p++) {
    /* Calculate the vertex and texture coordinates */
    float x2 = x + a->c[*p].bl * sx;
    float y2 = -y - a->c[*p].bt * sy;
    float w = a->c[*p].bw * sx;
    float h = a->c[*p].bh * sy;

    /* Advance the cursor to the start of the next character */
    x += a->c[*p].ax * sx;
    y += a->c[*p].ay * sy;

    /* Skip glyphs that have no pixels */
    if (!w || !h)
        continue;

    coords[c++] = (point) {
    x2, -y2, a->c[*p].tx, a->c[*p].ty};
    coords[c++] = (point) {
    x2 + w, -y2, a->c[*p].tx + a->c[*p].bw / a->w, a->c[*p].ty};
    coords[c++] = (point) {
    x2, -y2 - h, a->c[*p].tx, a->c[*p].ty + a->c[*p].bh / a->h};
    coords[c++] = (point) {
    x2 + w, -y2, a->c[*p].tx + a->c[*p].bw / a->w, a->c[*p].ty};
    coords[c++] = (point) {
    x2, -y2 - h, a->c[*p].tx, a->c[*p].ty + a->c[*p].bh / a->h};
    coords[c++] = (point) {
    x2 + w, -y2 - h, a->c[*p].tx + a->c[*p].bw / a->w, a->c[*p].ty + a->c[*p].bh / a->h};
}

/* Draw all the character on the screen in one go */
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof coords, coords, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, c);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);


}
```

**Font initiation**

```
bool Util::Font::init()
{
if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load Freetype!" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

if (FT_New_Face(ft, "res/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf", 0 , &face))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load font file!" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

shaderID = Util::Shader::loadShaders("res/shaders/font.vert", "res/shaders/font.frag");

samplerID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "textureSampler");
colorID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "color");

glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);

font12px = new Atlas(face, 12);
font24px = new Atlas(face, 24);
font48px = new Atlas(face, 48);

return true;
}
```

**The Font header inside of Utils.h**

```
namespace Font {

    static FT_Library ft;
    static FT_Face face;
    static GLuint shaderID;
    static GLuint samplerID;
    static GLuint colorID;
    static GLuint vertexBufferID;
    static GLuint coordID;

    bool init();

    struct point {
        GLfloat x;
        GLfloat y;
        GLfloat s;
        GLfloat t;

    };

    struct Atlas {
GLuint tex;     // texture object

int w;          // width of texture in pixels
int h;          // height of texture in pixels

struct {
    float ax;   // advance.x
    float ay;   // advance.y

    float bw;   // bitmap.width;
    float bh;   // bitmap.height;

    float bl;   // bitmap_left;
    float bt;   // bitmap_top;

    float tx;   // x offset of glyph in texture coordinates
    float ty;   // y offset of glyph in texture coordinates
} c[128];       // character information

 Atlas(FT_Face face, int height) {
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, height);
    FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;

    int roww = 0;
    int rowh = 0;
     w = 0;
     h = 0;

     memset(c, 0, sizeof c);

    /* Find minimum size for a texture holding all visible ASCII characters */
    for (int i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, i, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Loading character %c failed!\n", i);
            continue;
        }
        if (roww + g->bitmap.width + 1 >= 1024) {
            w = std::max(w, roww);
            h += rowh;
            roww = 0;
            rowh = 0;
        }
        roww += g->bitmap.width + 1;
        rowh = std::max(rowh, g->bitmap.rows);
    }

    w = std::max(w, roww);
    h += rowh;

    /* Create a texture that will be used to hold all ASCII glyphs */
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glUniform1i(samplerID, 0);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, w, h, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    /* We require 1 byte alignment when uploading texture data */
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    /* Clamping to edges is important to prevent artifacts when scaling */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    /* Linear filtering usually looks best for text */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    /* Paste all glyph bitmaps into the texture, remembering the offset */
    int ox = 0;
    int oy = 0;

    rowh = 0;

    for (int i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, i, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Loading character %c failed!\n", i);
            continue;
        }

        if (ox + g->bitmap.width + 1 >= 1024) {
            oy += rowh;
            rowh = 0;
            ox = 0;
        }

        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ox, oy, g->bitmap.width, g->bitmap.rows, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g->bitmap.buffer);
        c[i].ax = g->advance.x >> 6;
        c[i].ay = g->advance.y >> 6;

        c[i].bw = g->bitmap.width;
        c[i].bh = g->bitmap.rows;

        c[i].bl = g->bitmap_left;
        c[i].bt = g->bitmap_top;

        c[i].tx = ox / (float)w;
        c[i].ty = oy / (float)h;

        rowh = std::max(rowh, g->bitmap.rows);
        ox += g->bitmap.width + 1;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Generated a %d x %d (%d kb) texture atlas\n", w, h, w * h / 1024);
}

~Atlas() {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
}
};

    static Atlas *font48px;
    static Atlas *font24px;
    static Atlas *font12px;

    void render(const char *text, Atlas *atlas, float x, float y, float sx, float sy);
}
```

Comment: Which GPU? Where exactly crashes?

Comment: NVidia GeForce GTX 660 Ti. It crashes right on the glBindTexture call inside of the render method.I'm using GLFW for context creation and GLEW to get the OpenGL 3+ functions.

Comment: I know this is obvious but have you checked that a cannot be NULL when calling glBindTexture?

Comment: and GLEW loads opengl function successfully?

Comment: GLEW works correctly. What cannot be null?